# Ubuntu Raspberry PI CM4 u-boot modifications

Tags: raspberrypi

I have a custom board using the CM4 module, I would like to run Ubuntu but in order to support my board I need to make some minor changes to the u-boot bootloader.
I followed the steps on the wiki:[Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Create_a_partition_with_pi_firmware.2Fbootloader_files)

After copying the u-boot binary the device boots u-boot but has a CRC mismatch on the environment and wants to download a new image/dtb/kernel using tftp.
What step is missing in the manual to get a replacement u-boot?

Comment: Maybe the answer you're looking can be found at "Booting and installation" and by following the links there.

Comment: I have a working prebuilt image for the CM4, I only want to swap out the stock u-boot bootloader with my custom u-boot bootloader. Just to see how easy it is to modify a ubuntu distribution.